# asp.net core 2.2, appsettings.json is updated to azure devops no matter if exists in gitignore

Tags: c#, git, asp.net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a asp.net core 2.2 solution connected to azure devops. I have an original version of the appsettings.json uploaded to azure devops, however, due to some configurations I don't want to upload every time I sync, I added it into .gitignore file, however it continues marking it as modified, as checked in, etc. and whenever I run sync. it continues uploading it to azure. I stage any changes before pushing into azure and manually I unstage this file, however, for some reason when sync. it uploads it, modifiyng the content into azure devops.

I really need help.

Comment: Once you have it commited - it will be tracked even if it's in .gitignore. Use a local appsettings.development.json for things you don't want commited and ignore that. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Off topic, but you really really really shouldn't be using.net core 2.2 anymore as it is since end of 2019 end of life and doesn't receive any (security) patches anymore. Refer to the docs: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core